# GKGoal Avoid Boundary Obstacles

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics, gameplay-kit

I am seeming to have difficulty keeping my sprite nodes inside a map boundary that I have set up in the following way:

I have an `SKNode *enemy` that moves around an `SKScene` by goals and behaviors courtesy of `GameplayKit` from iOS 9. Currently the node wanders, and avoids obstacles that are defined `GKPolygonObstacle` objects. I have my bitmask set up so that any obstacle is deemd category **wall**, which the node is told to collide with (AKA disallow passing through).

In my `didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact` I am handling these collisions. All is working exactly as planned and there are no issues when manually moving this enemy.

**However**, the problem begins when I have the enemy wander around the scene through an `SKGoal *wanderGoal` set up as

```
    // Low --> 0.5     Lowest --> 0.25
    enemy.wanderGoal = [GKGoal goalToWander:low];
    [enemy.agent.behavior setWeight:lowest forGoal:enemy.wanderGoal];

    // Add obstacles to avoid for each of the inner map nodes
    // that act as impassible areas for the enemy to pass through.
    NSArray *obstacles = [SKNode obstaclesFromNodePhysicsBodies:innerMapArray];

    /** This goal does not change --> enemies will ALWAYS
     avoid the obstacles in the level map. This should always 
     be set to the highest priority of the enemy goals
     */
    enemy.avoidGoal = [GKGoal goalToAvoidObstacles:obstacles maxPredictionTime:10];
    // Highest --> 250
    [enemy.agent.behavior setWeight:highest forGoal:enemy.avoidGoal];
```

The enemy moves randomly as expected, and seems to avoid the obstacles most of the time...yet on the occasion the enemy **does** in fact pass through the map barrier. Let me expand on this:

The map barrier is essentially a rectangle, and I have set up 2 nodes that act as a shell that represent the left half and the right half of this shape. These nodes have a thickness of 100 points so they are not simply `CGPath` refs but rather shapes. They act as these two brackets act:  [] (my halves are flush touching at the middle).

**My question is such:**

- How can I prevent the enemy from passing through these obstacles with using either physics with the bitmask categories, or by the goal behavior? (Or both together)

I understand that while a `GKGoal` is a suggested behavior it does not *guarantee* this goal to be reached (but it can be ~95% sure it wont happen as [Apple's AgentsCatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AgentsCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) shows). **But**, what I don't understand is why the enemy does not simply "slide" along the edge of the boundary as the goal tells it to (try to) "pass" through such boundary.

This "sliding" behavior **does** happen when I manually move the enemy around the scene, and as I attempt to move it passed a boundary deemed an obstacle, it slides towards the direction that I am having it move (just as any video game does that has map boundaries).

## SO

If someone can help me prevent this from happening / explain how to approach preventing the enemy from ever passing through these (supposedly) "impassible" areas, I would be most appreciative.

**FYI:** If you are unclear with what I am describing / how I have created any objects, please ask and I will provide more info to help.

Comment: I thought this was a well-written question that deserves an answer.

Comment: Not sure how much clearer I could have been here.. maybe nobody knows a fix. Good thing the project was completed in other ways. Thanks everyone for the helpful help! Glad I spent 30 minutes writing this.. in order to avoid the snobby "Show code" or "Too vague" junk.